# installing both windows and ubuntu on SSD issue

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, ssd

guys I installed windows 10 and ubuntu on my laptop (hp pavilion dv6 quad edition) which I have SSD as sda and HDD as sdb.
I repartitioned the SSD to 2 partitions one for each OS,first I installed windows on sda1 and then ubuntu on sda2, after installing ubuntu I booted to a live boot repair USB to fix grub with recommended option, it got fixed of course, but ended up showing windows 10 boot loader on sdb1 in grub menu which is odd because I installed it on sda1, how is that even possible? and it is booting up really slow, there is no problem with ubuntu.
any idea how to fix this?

Comment: My guess is that by partitioning first Windows may have placed an EFI partition and a reserved partition on the HDD. Can you look to see if that is the case? I’d be inclined to start again, delete all partitions, install Windows to the whole of the SSD, it will probably create, 3 partitions. Then install Ubuntu alongside Windows, letting the installer do its thing to shrink the Windows partition. Let us know how you get on.

Comment: ok I've checked the sdb partition, the weirdest thing happened, apparently after installing, the sdb1 partition which was ext4, now somehow changed into ntfs with a boot flag!!! how does it even possible? without formatting a partition?

Comment: Both the Windows and Ubuntu installers will manipulate partitions and perform the appropriate formatting as part of the installation process. You don’t need to do any partitioning yourself before the install but you can choose to in the Ubuntu install process (and possibly in the Windows install process but I haven’t tried that)